# how does the manipulation of inputs type date work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

so i was trying to creat a page that asks the user to enter some infos including the birthday and then displays these informations in initially empty spans but i was wondering how does it work if

```
<input type="date" id="birth">
```

and then inside the script tags

```
<script>
var a = document.getElementById('birth').value;
</script>
```

is now the "a" a new date() with set values? or how does it work exactly?
because i was trying to execute a function if the user clicks on a button with the onclick event and it doesn t get executed which lead me to question how does the date type work to begin with

i tried to change the type date to a type text and let the user enter the date as "dd/mm/yyyy"
and then collect it but again i didnt know if per example we had

```
<input type="text" id="birth2">
```

if i do a

```
<script>
var b = document.getElementById('birth2').value; 
</script>
```

can i transform the "b" into an Array() (each item is seperated by "/") and then control if the date is correct(no negative values, the month is between 1 and 12 .....)?
if anyone knows anything about it please let me know

Comment: it's about types formats. You can access the value of an HTML date type field in 2 ways : Either by its value in "text (string)" with the `.value` property, or in "javascript-date-type" with the `.valueAsDate` property. Please note the valueAsDate  is in `universal time (T0)`, while the .value  is in `local time`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `<input type="date">`, the value you get from **document.getElementById('birth').value** is a string representing the date in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. It's not automatically converted to a JavaScript **Date** object. If you want to work with it as a **Date** object, you need to convert it explicitly:

---

```
<input type="date" id="birth">
    <button onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
    
    <script>
    function displayDate() {
      var dateString = document.getElementById('birth').value;
      var dateObject = new Date(dateString);
      console.log(dateObject);
    }
    </script>
```

---

If you choose to use `<input type="text">` for the date input, you can split the value into an array and validate the date manually:

```
<input type="text" id="birth2">
<button onclick="validateDate()">Validate Date</button>

<script>
function validateDate() {
  var dateString = document.getElementById('birth2').value;
  var dateArray = dateString.split('/');

  var day = parseInt(dateArray[0], 10);
  var month = parseInt(dateArray[1], 10);
  var year = parseInt(dateArray[2], 10);

  // Perform your validation here
  if (isValidDate(day, month, year)) {
    console.log('Valid date');
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid date');
  }
}

function isValidDate(day, month, year) {
  // Perform your validation logic
  // For example: Check if day, month, and year are within valid ranges
  return day > 0 && day <= 31 && month > 0 && month <= 12 && year > 0;
}
</script>
```

In the **isValidDate** function, you can add more complex validation rules according to your requirements.

Comment: `let [ day,month,year ] = dateString.split('/').map(Number);` ...